# Whole notebook slows down after opening Drawing Tools

Tags: notebooks, drawing

Is there a way to create own, simplified toolbox that would perform faster?
I found the toolbox source, but I'm looking for an example on how to extract methods for e.g. drawing lines.

Comment: Try drawing them programmatically. It pays off.

Comment: Well, yes I agree, but I'm aiming at being able to make simple pictures realtime during lecture.